# Is there a way to correctly use an Image in XNA and windows forms...?

Tags: winforms, xna, texture2d

I just don't quite know how to handle this situation I'm dealing with.

I have a image of terrain tiles.  In fact, here is a picture of it:

[image]

I've been working on my Map Editor for my game which has some windows forms in it like this:

[image]

Now, the problem is that both the XNA and the Windows Forms needs the image of the sprite tiles.  Is there a way to handle this nicely or am I going to have to have two copies of the image (one for the WinForms and one for the XNA)?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need two copies of the image. Have you looked at the WinForms examples on AppHub?

http://create.msdn.com/education/catalog/sample/winforms_series_2